# Connection reset by peer In the Htpp client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, httpclient

I have the following code it is throwing the error. How can we call API's with the httpclient without the connection reset errors.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)

```
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() {
    return java.net.http.HttpClient.newHttpClient();
}
    
HttpRequest req =
    HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(url))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenValue)
        .header("User-Agent", "admins-api")
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(inputJson))
        .build();
```

Comment: Most probably the server has closed the connection without waiting for the rest of the request to arrive. The server probably doesn't find the request headers it expects. IIANM "reset by peer" usually means that there was some inflight data in the connection at the time of closing. (PS: a more appropriate tag for this question would be java-http-client)